# how to merge values in a list of map in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

say I have data structure like List< MAP< String, List>>, I only want to keep the List in map's value,

Like, I want to convert following example:

> x = [{"key1" => ["list1", "list1"]}, {"key2" => ["list2", "list2"]},
>   {"key3" => ["list3", "list3"]}]

to:

> y = [["list1", "list1"], ["list2", "list2"], ["list3", "list3"]]

Is there any quick way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest thing that comes to mind is to leverage `flat_map`.

```
x = [ { "key1" => ["list1", "list1"] }, 
      { "key2" => ["list2", "list2"] }, 
      { "key3" => ["list3", "list3"] }]

y = x.flat_map(&:values)

=> [["list1", "list1"], ["list2", "list2"], ["list3", "list3"]]
```

`flat_map` is an instance method on Enumerable (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map)

`values` is an instance method on Hash (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-values)

Comment: lesson learnt, thanks! what about merging all the values get get something like ["list1", "list1", "list2", "list2", "list3", "list3"]. I can only do it by running another for loop based on your output... Thanks

Comment: You can just tack a `flatten` onto the end, ala: `y = x.flat_map(&:values).flatten`

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 1 key in those hashes then you can do it like this:

```rb
y = x.map { |h| h.values[0] }
```

Comment: lesson learnt, thanks! what about merging all the values get get something like ["list1", "list1", "list2", "list2", "list3", "list3"]. I can only do it by running another for loop based on your output... Thanks